# Does bootstrap let me to modify his own classes to make a page responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating project based in html and css. I have created this code in bootstrap inside a container and I want this to be responsive.

```html
<div class=" container">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 client "> <b>SEI GIÀ CLIENTE? ACCEDI </b>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3  col-sm-3 labelField">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4  col-sm-4 labelField">
          <strong><br>EMAIL</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8  col-sm-8">
          <input class="ut" type="mail">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 labelField">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 labelField">
          <strong><br>PASSWORD</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
          <input class="ut" type="mail">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3  col-sm-3 col-xs-3 "></div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 pass"><a href="#"> Hai dimenticato la password?</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3"></div>
  </div>


  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 ">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/entra.png" class="img-responsive registrati ">
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 ">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/fb.png" class="img-responsive registrati ">
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>



  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 ">
      <div class="divider"></div>

      </div
```

Here is my css:

```css
.registrati {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 338px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  width: 33%px;
}
.pass {
  font-style: Arial black;
  color: black;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin-left: 339px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Here is what my result should look like:
[image]
The result is not responsive. My question is have I done something wrong or bootstrap doesnt let me to modify the classes as I did? So what should I do to make this responsive?
All the scripts and links required for responsivity are in my page but not here for a shorter demo. Thanks!

Comment: The Bootstrap grid works based on column elements having specific widths and margins assigned; you can not just overwrite those willy-nilly, and expect the grid to still work. Do what you want to do on elements _inside_ the columns, but don’t mess with the whole grid.

Answer (score 1):

I can't run your snippet on my Mac but just by looking at your code, I would remove `width: 80%; height: 100%;` If you really want it to be responsive the "bootstrap way", try letting it handle your div containers in terms of sizes first. Have you tried that?

Looks fine in terms of responsiveness without your stylesheet: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/23755/

**EDIT:** those margins seem pretty large? Maybe it just looks like it's not responsive because of the huge margins. Can you maybe provide a sketch of what it should look like?

**EDIT2:** Here is my answer: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/23757/ I cleaned it up a bit. Your problem was that you had way too many divs and columns; you should check out Bootstrap's grid [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) again and use `col-md-offset` if you want to offset things by design.

Comment: @Doe I just edited mine. My jsfiddle without your CSS looks fine right? Are you sure you wired up Bootstrap properly in your html?

Comment: Ok it is responsive without css but I rally need to fix the layout so I need to modify the margins and spaces. How am I suposed to do that without css?

Comment: @Doe of course you can use margins :) Can you give me a basic sketch of what it should look like? I am happy to help

Comment: @Doe Thanks! I have just added my solution :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all I am assuming that you have included [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) css and js properly. Going further you don't need additional css for making your page responsive. Bootstrap does that. Always remember bootstrap has 12 columns in a row. So u need to use it properly for your page to show responsiveness.

```
    <div class="container contain">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 text-center">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="https://www.google.co.in/logos/doodles/2016/2016-doodle-fruit-games-day-12-5125886484414464.3-scta.png" class="registrati img-responsive">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-4 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 pass text-center">
                <a href="https://www.google.co.in/logos/doodles/2016/2016-doodle-fruit-games-day-12-5125886484414464.3-scta.png">
                    Hai dimenticato la password?
                </a> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 text-center">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="https://www.google.co.in/logos/doodles/2016/2016-doodle-fruit-games-day-12-5125886484414464.3-scta.png" class="registrati img-responsive">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```